# Convert String DateTime to User Locale Date Time

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime, locale

My string format : **10/11/2016 01:00 AM**

I want to convert this **String to DateTime to support in every user's locale format**

I tried Date.parse, Date.valueOf but am not getting expected value.

Any help is appreciable thanks!.

Comment: Assuming you mean that the format is fixed (and does not match the user's local settings), the bad news is that there isn't a built in method to help with the parsing and you'll have to write your own code. See [this example](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105395/apex-date-datetime-parse-or-valueof-string-gets-error/105406#105406).

Comment: the format is MM/dd/yyyy with AM and PM whatever will be.  So this is supporting for united states and indian format but it is not supporting for singapore and some other countries due to 24-hour format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format with `userinfo.getTimeZone();`

```
DateTime dtNow = //any date here 

String formattedDate = dtNow .format('yyyy-MM-dd',  UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString());
```

### Updates

Try below code snippet to convert the string to DateTime.

```
String val = '2015-12-01T12:44:00.000+0000'; 

DateTime date1 = (DateTime)Json.deserialize('"'+val+'"', DateTime.class);

System.debug(date1)  ---> 2015-12-01 12:44:00

String dateformat = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:sssZ';
String abc = date1.format(dateformat,''+userinfo.getTimeZone().toString());
system.debug(abc);
```

Comment: I gave like this, 
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.parse(obj.stringfield); 

String formattedDate = dtNow .format('yyyy-MM-dd', userinfo.getTimeZone());

but getting error in 2nd line, _Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Datetime].format(String, TimeZone)_

Comment: @Prince ahh this is `UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString()`.. updated answer pls check

Comment: My input from visualforce page is **10/11/2016 02:30 PM
**. In the apex code am converting this to DateTime. When the user is from some other place with the format **11/11/2016 14:30 getting error while clicking the save button in visualforce page saying that 'Invalid Date/Time'. 
**

Comment: So when I pass the string input to convert DateTime it is getting error in some countries. I am parsing string to DateTime convertToDateTime = DateTime.parse(input); like this.

Comment: @Prince issue with parsing and timmezone both ?

Comment: @Prince in VF page provide date picker simple so user will not enter invalid date

Comment: Date Time field in visualforce page is read only field. We are filling it with client side timezone api for given address in some fields.

Comment: @Prince check my updated Answer.. if the `DateTime.parse` giving issue then tr with `Json.deserialize()`

Comment: @Prince any updates here?

Comment: I just created new instance of DateTime from string date time to support in every locale with the method DateTime.newInstance();

Comment: @Prince so this issue is resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following link, hope it help.
[Date/Time Field - Independent of User Locale](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000D6I6IAK)

Comment: I think the question in link is different from Mine. In the link, the user dont want to change the date and time regardless of the locale. But I want to convert this according to user locale.

Comment: Hi @Prince, I've try the recommended by Ratan. That should be match your question. 

"String timeTxt = '20:48 11/10/2016';
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(timeTxt);
System.debug('Time: '+ dt.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'));
TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
System.debug('Time zone 2: '+ dt.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss',  'America/New_York'));"